# When will a ball running between two downwards slopes stop going back and forth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, momentum

Two angles $a$ and $b$ meet at a point, making an angle $c$ between them.

$a$ and $b$ are all $0 < \theta < π/2$. $c$ is $π/2 < \theta < π$

$a$ is to the left and opens to the left, $b$ to the right and opens to the right.

The slope is frictionless.

A ball starts rolling down the left slope. When the ball hits the slope intersection, the velocity angle changes from angle $a$ to angle $b$, but the ball loses momentum by $\sin(c) * v$. When eventually pulled back by gravity (9.8N), it rolls over the intersection the other way, etc..

- Will the ball ever stop moving back and forth? When?
- In the real world, if the slopes were connected as a continuous, perfectly concave surface instead, would the ball ever actually stop? When?
- Is the momentum loss equation mentioned above an ok apporoximation for, say, simple 2D computer game physics?

Comment: For 1 and 2, I don't know; In the program, the ball just rocks back and forth with ever smaller movements (I guess, until the floating point precision is exhausted). For 3; The solution to _force_ the ball to stop it's motion was setting a threshold at a certain velocity. After testing the behavior with angles of 5,10,15,20 degrees etc, I've so far landed on a threshold of 0.3 px pr sec/60 (100 px = 1 meter). Does that answer your question? If need be, the situation can be visualized [here](http://cloud.holbrook.no/public.php?service=files&t=ddab6155d4f849355f56f4b26e49222d)

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange? There are some problems with this post. First, homework-like questions *require* that you show what you have already tried to solve the problem. Second, the question is hard to understand. Rather than describe the setup in words, please use a simple diagram. Finally, in the comments you mention "the program" but you have not referred to this at all in the question so we have no idea what you're talking about. Make your questions crystal clear.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify things for a newcomer. The only thing I really wanted to ask was when a ball would stop moving, on a mere hypothetical level, and just out of mere curiosity from playing around with an animation function in C++ and SDL. Maybe I should just post a new question? What is customary to do here in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

If the slope is truly frictionless, then the ball will never stop moving. You are assuming that after passing through the V at the bottom, it will roll back up the other slope. But

1. It is not rolling but sliding (no friction - no torque to make the ball roll)
2. When it hits the V, it will bounce - so it will lose contact with the surface

Exactly how it behaves after that will depend on the exact geometry - but since there is no loss mechanism, the ball must keep moving.

See this diagram:

[image]

The red vectors are the velocity just before and just after hitting the V - the blue vectors are the components parallel and perpendicular to the second surface. The component parallel to the second surface is unaffected by the collision; the perpendicular component is reversed. After this, the ball will exhibit a chaotic bouncing pattern: the exact trajectory will depend entirely on the initial conditions / angles.

But unless there is a way for energy to be lost, the ball will keep bouncing forever.

As for the second question - in the real world, there would be losses and rolling along a smooth concave surface would eventually cause the ball to stop; as for the third question - in a computer game you can do whatever you want... "real" physics need not get in your way.